# Tor Browser Bundle/Tor and iptables: seeking a working setup

Tags: networking, iptables, tor, tor-browser

I am trying to set a policy for iptables for Tor and particularly Tor Browser Bundle, something apparently rare, judging from searches online which have never found me an iptables setup for TBB and whose complete default ports (socks, control, trans and DNS) are unmentioned. Many iptables configurations associated with Tor are complicated, mostly in the name of transproxying, here a secondary concern. Typical desktop Tor policies are unsuitable for adaptation.

My concern is to run TBB with a tighter environment with minimal rule set by specifying it exclusively in iptables, something I have only found possible by specifying tor ports (and which should be possible anyway), to isolate DNS to TBB, and to make sure the connection is maintained without compromising isolation (ie. avoiding DNS leaks) and minimal additional packet transit. This is more of a challenge given mobile usage.

So far I have been able to specify TBB's ports and DNS in its torrc file, after a few attempts at watching respecified defaults apparently break TBB's operation altogether (reassigned port numbers did not, a quirk): TBB will now start with my specified ports without complaint.

A basic iptables policy, shown here, consists of minimal NAT rules for mapping DNS to the tor DNS port and dumping UDP to port 9, (discard according to /etc/services) a filter RELATED ESTABLISHED rule and the three outgoing ports for Tor itself (the loopback allow and icmp/igmp blocks are disposable details, as far as I know, but shown). I am unclear as to whether Tor's assigned DNS port must be specified (other than the NAT redirect) - I have seen this done, but given the inability to otherwise isolate TBB (such as by UID), would have thought it a leak risk. According to what little info I have been able to find, Tor routes DNS through the onion routing and performs DNS at the end of its exit node: but does it's own DNS port need to be open in filter rules?

As can be seen in the -nvL readout, the Tor ports themselves show no packets outgoing, and after loopback all packets are dumped in a final DROP policy added at the end of filter rules.

My initial assumption was that, in the absence of seperate DNS and DHCP allows, the connection is merely dying. If I switch back to a clearnet policy with DNS and DHCP allowed in filter, the connection must be restarted to regain access to the net at all, suggesting this. In addition, if I -nvL the clearnet policy, DNS and DHCP ports can be seen to transit no data, all of which must be going through the general all-protocol allow, rendering DNS and DHCP meaningless for most public connections. This is problematic in general in mobile contexts where it is valuable to be able to control (or repossess) DNS lookups from ISPs, captive portals, etc.

Tor's own logs typically show 'general socks server failure', though it is also unclear to me how Tor can get this far at all if no packets are being shifted by socks, control and transports.

I have tried including UDP in the NAT table DNS redirect (no change), allowing DHCP in INPUT and OUTPUT filter rules (no change), and including the assigned Tor DNS port (here 5353) in OUTPUT filter rules (no change). If a standard clearnet policy is restored, TBB will run successfully and quickly resolve the net, indicating that the problem is definitely being caused by iptables.

TBB IPTables policy:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4:240]
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5353
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p igmp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 9251 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 9250 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 9240 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

IPTables output (-nvL):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 8 packets, 798 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 9514  534K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0     
    0     0 REJECT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     2    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    2   181 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 9514  534K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:9251
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:9250
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:9240
   35  2300 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Tor log 1:

```
01/12/2018 12:06:17.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
01/12/2018 12:06:17.600 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default")
01/12/2018 12:06:30.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all 
01/12/2018 12:06:30.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9250
01/12/2018 12:06:30.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
01/12/2018 12:06:30.900 [NOTICE] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
01/12/2018 12:06:30.900 [NOTICE] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9240 
01/12/2018 12:06:32.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
01/12/2018 12:06:32.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
01/12/2018 12:06:34.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:47779 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:06:34.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:38980 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:06:34.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 169.229.59.75:46328 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:06:34.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:08:46.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9240 
(Closing, etc.)
```

Tor log 2:

```
01/12/2018 12:10:06.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.  
01/12/2018 12:10:21.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9250 
01/12/2018 12:10:21.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
01/12/2018 12:10:21.800 [NOTICE] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
01/12/2018 12:10:21.800 [NOTICE] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9240 
01/12/2018 12:10:23.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
01/12/2018 12:10:23.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 85.31.186.26:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 37.218.245.14:38224 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.95.36.142:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 38.229.1.78:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:15937 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 85.17.30.79:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 38.229.33.83:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 85.31.186.98:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:10:24.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 37.218.240.34:40035 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/12/2018 12:11:01.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9240 
(Closing, etc.)
```